# The static method...should be accessed in a static way

Tags: java, static

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person Gunnar = new Person();
        Person Sven = new Person();
        Dog Doggy = new Dog();
        Dog Doggi = new Dog();

        Gunnar.setName("Gunnar");
        Gunnar.setAge(20);
        Gunnar.setHeight(215);

        Sven.setName("Sven");
        Sven.setAge(55);
        Sven.setHeight(178);

        Sven.sayHello(Gunnar);
    }
}
```

Java wants me to change `Sven` and `Gunnar` (name of the two Person objects) to Person in the `.setName` lines so it would be `Person.setName("Gunnar");` and `Person.setName("Sven");`. But, that won't work since there would be no way of telling which one is which. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also don't mind the dog code.

Here's the code for the Person class:

```
public class Person {
    static int age;
    static int height;
    static String name;

    public void sayHello(Person name) {
        System.out.println("Hello!" +name);
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        Person.age = age;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        Person.height = height;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName(String name) {
        Person.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided the source code to your `Person` class. It is likely that you erroneously declared its methods `static`.

Comment: If the methods are static, why are you invoking them on variables?

Comment: did java ask you to change Sven and Gunnar?  How did java ask you?

Comment: Try to stick to the naming conventions and start variable names with lowercase letters. Easier to distinguish them from classes and prevent this kind of mistakes.

Comment: "The static method setName(String) from the type Person should be accessed in a static way."

Comment: It's only a style suggestion. It will still compile and run OK.

Comment: @Tony I appreciate that you're trying to help by editing this post, but there are a many other problems in it. In the future, please improve everything you can in a post before suggesting an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your methods correctly (from logical point of view)
but apparently you have declared them incorrectly (as static).
Make them instance methods by removing the static modifier.
That should fix your problem. And learn the the difference between
static and instance methods (seems you haven't quite yet).

In particular `getName` and `setName` should not be static.

Comment: Guess I should start writing my own getters and setters instead of letting eclipse auto-generate them for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Philip3412 Well, no, Eclipse is good at that :) I use that feature all the time. I guess your `name` variable was static when you asked Eclipse to auto-generate the getter and the setter.

Comment: That's fully possible. Thanks for the help once again :)